# matplotib: two overlaid transparent images look different when saved as svg or png

Tags: matplotlib, svg, plot, png, alpha-transparency

I'm trying to overlay two transparent images with matplotlib and save the result, but the result looks different depending on the file type. Specifically it's much more washed-out when saving to svg.

Here's an example. In this case, I could just add the two images before displaying them, but this is just a simple example. In reality what I'm trying to do is more complicated (images of different sizes with different colormaps), so they have to be plotted separately.

Example code:

```
f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(2,2))
ax.imshow(np.eye(3), alpha=.5)
ax.imshow(np.eye(3)[::-1], alpha=.5)
f.savefig('example.png')
f.savefig('example.svg')
```

The png file looks just like it does on the screen, but the svg file looks washed out. I would like to know how to save as svg, without the washed-out effect (i.e. it should look like it does on the screen).

As a bonus question, why does the png plot appear different depending on the order in which I plot the transparent images? The second image always looks stronger. Interestingly, in the svg, both are equally washed out.

Example saved as png:

[image: saved as png]

Example saved as svg:

[image: saved as svg]

matplotlib version: 3.1.3
python version: 3.7.7

Thanks for any tips!

Comment: Are these related to your query ? 1. https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/10035
2.https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/17049

Comment: @AshlinJP possibly! I can't really tell

Answer (score 0):

I'll post what I think is going on, but if someone can answer with more legit information I'll accept it.

I think that every time you call imshow with an alpha value, it blends the current image in the axis with the new image, using (new * alpha + current * (1-alpha)). The problem with this is that if you display 10 images each with alpha 0.5, then the first image is attenuated to nothing by the iterative blending, whereas the last image gets to be 50% of the final result. Nonetheless this is apparently the method used for rendering to the screen and saving to png.

In contrast, when saving to svg, it saves each image as a separate overlay with its own alpha. The svg container or renderer then uses some more intelligent method that considers all overlaid images at once. However, in my particular case, this leads to a more washed-out look because all the images are partially transparent.